# Angular 2 - How to control text shown in URL address bar history

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

After navigating around our app, when you look at the URL address bar history it just shows:

- AppName
- AppName
- AppName
- etc.

How can I show the full route, or control what is shown?

e.g.

- AppName/Detail/1
- AppName/List
- AppName/LandingPage

I believe this should be possible as the angular documentation says: [And the router logs activity in the browser's history journal so the back and forward buttons work as well.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

Comment: **browser history** what does this means? URL address bar or Privacy History

Comment: URL address bar. As shown when right-clicking the back button.

Comment: No you need to disable the back button and handle the back navigation in your application